# Keep inner values of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a tiff with lakes, which I converted into a 2D array. I would like to keep the outline of the lakes in a 2D array.

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

with rasterio.open('myfile.tif') as dtm:
    array = dtm.read(1)

array[array>0] = 1
array = array.astype(float)
array[array==0] = np.nan
```

My array looks like this now, a lake can be seen in the upper right corner:

```
     [[      nan       nan       nan ... 2888.001  **2877.458  2867.5798**]
     [      nan       nan       nan ... 2890.188  **2879.2876 2869.0415**]
     [      nan       nan       nan ... 2892.2622 2880.9907 2870.4985]
     ...
     [      nan       nan       nan ...       nan       nan       nan]
     [      nan       nan       nan ...       nan       nan       nan]
     [      nan       nan       nan ...       nan       nan       nan]]
```

I wish to keep the outline of the lakes I have to set all values to nan, which are NOT located next to a nan (marked in bold).

I have tried:

```
array[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.nan
```

However, this converts ALL inner values of the entire array to nan, not just the inner values of the lakes.

If you know of a completely different way how to keep the outline of the lakes (maybe with rasterio), I would also be thankful.
I hope I made clear what I mean with inner values of the lakes.

Tim

Comment: Does a lake always appear in a corner?

Comment: No, it can appear anywhere in the array. Sorry I did not make this clear.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67056127/8345628